# std::get for own class with tuple as member

Tags: c++, templates, std

I have a class like this:

```
 template<typename ... TTypes>
 class Composite {
 public:
     std::tuple<TTypes...> &getRefValues() { return values; }   
 private:
     std::tuple<TTypes...> values;
 };
```

Can I define `std::get` for my class Composite? It should basically call the already defined `std::get` for the private tuple values.

I was able to implement a customized get function when the return type is known (e.g. for an int array member) but I don't know how to realize get when the return type can be an arbitrary type (depending on the components' type of the tuple values)?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. You should define it in your app's namespace.

Comment: @RSahu: Why not? "A program may add a template specialization
for any standard library template to namespace `std` only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type" (plus a couple of other conditions). That's the case here.

Comment: Even if I define it in the app's namespace, how can I realize such a get method with an arbitrary return type?

Comment: @MikeSeymour Function templates cannot be partially specialized though. Also, `std::get` accepts an instance of `tuple`, so the OP could not specialize it for instances of `Composite`. They would have to add an overload, which is not allowed.

Comment: @moo Examine how `std::get` for `std::tuple` deduces its return type.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Thanks, that's a good reason why not.

Comment: @moo: In C++14 or later, just use `auto` to deduce the return type. In C++11, use `decltype` or `tuple_element::type`.

Comment: Thanks for the hints! That helped a lot.

Comment: @MikeSeymour and Andy Prowl, thanks for the discussion, and bringing clarity to my suggestion,  while I was I at a work meeting :)

Comment: @MikeSeymour s/`auto`/`decltype(auto)`/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do:

```
template <std::size_t I, typename... Ts>
auto get(Composite<Ts...>& composite)
-> decltype(std::get<I>(composite.getRefValues()))
{
    return std::get<I>(composite.getRefValues());
}
```

Note: In C++14, you may omit the `-> decltype(..)` part.

Comment: I have found a solution on my own in the meantime. But thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here is my solution. Thanks everyone:

```
template<typename ... TTypes>
class Composite {
public:
    Composite(TTypes... t) {
        std::tuple<TTypes...> tuple(t...);
        values = tuple;
    } 

    std::tuple<TTypes...> &getRefValues() { return values; }    
private:
    std::tuple<TTypes...> values;
};

namespace std {
template<size_t I, typename ... TTypes>
    auto get(Composite<TTypes ...> &t) -> typename std::tuple_element<I, std::tuple<TTypes...>>::type { 
        return std::get<I>(t.getRefValues());
    }
}

int main() {
    Composite<int, char, double> c(13, 'c', 13.5);
    std::cout << std::get<0>(c) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<1>(c) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<2>(c) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```